# Curl GET request is not giving any output in body

Tags: shell, curl, get, ssl-certificate, postman

Via Postman the Api which i am using is:-

[https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapi/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"details"{"Cert_Name":"cert1"}}}](https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapi/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA=%7B%22operation%22:%7B%22details%22%7B%22Cert_Name%22:%22cert1%22%7D%7D%7D)

with authtoken in header `"AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"`

When I send the get request via postman I get my certificate in the response body which is correct

Now I need to fetch this cert via curl command, so I created these two commands but when I execute them they connect to the server but the body of the response is coming empty.

curl -g -k -v -X GET [https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"details"{"Cert_Name":"cert1"}}}](https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA=%7B%22operation%22:%7B%22details%22%7B%22Cert_Name%22:%22cert1%22%7D%7D%7D) -H "AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"

curl -k -v -X GET https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts -H "AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" -d "INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"details"{"Cert_Name":"cert1"}}}"

Comment: Those quotes won't be welcomed by the shell, you should do URI encoding on your query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because the **`GET`** parameter doesn't support `-d` parameter. So this type of code will never work.

```
curl -k -v -X GET https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts -H "AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" -d "INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"details"{"Cert_Name":"cert1"}}}"
```

Secondly the **`GET`** parameter only sends the data through the url itself so the **`INPUT_DATA`** needs to be in the URL itself like this one

```
curl -g -k -v -X GET https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"details"{"Cert_Name":"cert1"}}} -H "AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
```

But the URL dosent support the braces and quotes `{} ""` and  to what i did was converted the **`INPUT_DATA`** to the `URL` format. So the actual working code is this one.

```
curl -g -k -v -X GET https://myCertManager.com/api/pik/restapt/MyCerts?INPUT_DATA=%7B%22operation%22%3A%7B%22details%22%7B%22Cert_Name%22%3A%22cert1%22%7D%7D%7D -H "AUTHTOKEN: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In postman if its working , you can generate equalent curl command by clicking the code  button on the right to[ corner , it will create the curl code snipet for you

Comment: already tried that, but its not working. i have found solution also, Thanks :)